# Using Google play Services for my Emulator

Tags: android

I followed the [***This Link here***](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527) to install two apk's

1. [com.android.vending.apk](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?pxpjfkveemq29qk)
2. [com.google.android.gms.apk](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?zn8wna5wf4ek5le)

I followed the path as ::

```
C:\Users\<your user name>\Downloads\adb install com.android.vending.apk
```

I am getting this infinate message like below

[image]

It tells .... there is more than one device emulator

But i have only one::

[image]

How can i solve this

### [edit]

[image]

Comment: if you need Google Play on Emulator - you can install http://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: #adb devices  - for checking connected devices

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Please see the edit .... what command can i give there ? .... documentation is confusing !

Comment: #adb kill-server / #adb start-server / #adb connect "192.168.56.103"

Comment: or try #adb disconnect "device ip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a specific device/emulator:

```
$ adb -s emulator-5554 install com.android.vending.apk
```